# Cursor problem on ubuntu 18.04 after suspending?

Tags: suspend, power-management

i have installed ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop 6 yeasr old sony vaio. before that i had ubuntu 14.10 running perfectly but after installing 18.04 i got a problem when i closed laptop and then open. i cannot key in password to wake up my laptop. I tried to suspend by power key, the situation is the same. so changing from suspend mode to resume make cursor not working ( keyboard does not respond to pressing but the mouse pointer is working normal and other functions are ok openning folders, play musics etc. are normal. with my brother help i installed and tried using old kernel 4.7.10c32x64core2h2pre1 the problem was fixed.Please somebody help ! thanks